# error: 'hash' is not a class template

Tags: c++, c++11, hash

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template<> // Voxel has voxel.position which is a IVec2 containing 2 values, it also has a bool value
struct hash<Voxel> {  
size_t operator()(const Voxel & k) const  
    {  
        return Math::hashFunc(k.position);  
    }  
};  

template<typename T> // This was already given
inline size_t hashFunc(const Vector<T, 2>& _key)
{
    std::hash<T> hashfunc;
    size_t h = 0xbd73a0fb;
    h += hashfunc(_key[0]) * 0xf445f0a9;
    h += hashfunc(_key[1]) * 0x5c23b2e1;
    return h;
}
```

My main

```
int main()
{
    Voxel t{ 16,0,true };
    std::hash(t);
}
```

Right now i am writing on an specialisation for std::hash. Now the online submission page always returns the following errors for my code. I don't know why and what i did wrong.

```
error: 'hash' is not a class template struct hash<>
```

and

```
error: no match for call to '(const std::hash<Math::Vector<int, 2ul> >)   (const Math::Vector<int, 2ul>&)' noexcept(declval<const_Hash((declval<const_Key&>()))>.
```

My own compiler only throws

```
error: The argument list for "class template" std :: hash "" is missing.
```

Comment: #include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

Comment: not changing anything, still same errors as before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are specializing `std::hash<>` in the global namespace and this is ill-formed.

The specialization must be declared in the same namespace, `std`. See the example for [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash):

```
// custom specialization of std::hash can be injected in namespace std
namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<S>
    {
        typedef S argument_type;
        typedef std::size_t result_type;
        result_type operator()(argument_type const& s) const
        ...
```

Comment: thank you. that got rid of most errors only the error: no match for call to '(const std::hash<Math::Vector<int, 2ul> >) (const Math::Vector<int, 2ul>&)'
  noexcept(declval<const _Hash&>()(declval<const _Key&>()))> remains.

Comment: @FabianPatzlaff Your code is incomplete, this is probably why your question is downvoted. Post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @FabianPatzlaff That error is probably because you do not include the header file with your specialization of `std::hash<Voxel>`.

Answer (score 9):

For posterity, I got the same error message when I had forgotten to `#include <functional>`.